# Is it possible for an Earth-sized planet to have a liquid water core

Tags: planets

Is it possible for a planet like Naboo to exist?

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding, Gnorshk. Please have a look at the [help center](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), and/or [how to write a good question](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/3624/how-to-write-the-perfect-question). Your question might be a good one if you spend a little more time to flesh it out. Describe what it means exactly to be "like Naboo". Add your own research and think about using one of the science related tags. If you are unsure what would fit, have a look [here](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/3702/)

Comment: Additionally, please provide details concerning Naboo, as not everyone is likely to know all (or any) of the details concerning the planet. As is, answerers would need to do research before they could start answering, and all the relevant material would be located in places other than this question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, Naboo can not exist.

The immense pressure in the core of a planet (Earth: $~300 \text{ GPa}$) would turn the water into exotic forms of ice [image]

So, the core will definitely **not** be liquid. Travelling through there is not advisable.

Then there is the problem of dry land - the continents would need to be floating, so they need to be lighter than water. (on planetary scales, stone is not rigid enough to withstand deformation)